# How to enable hot reload when using Webpack in watch mode and Firebase emulators:start

Tags: webpack, firebase-hosting, firebase-tools, react-hot-loader, webpack-hot-middleware

I'm starting off a new project and I though it would be nice to use the full firebase emulators suite.

Se here's what I've thought could work:

```
// THIS IS MY package.json SCRIPT

"start-firebase-build": "set NODE_ENV=development_firebase&& webpack --config webpack.config.js",
```

**webpack.config.js**

That webpack config will do the following:

```
if (DEVELOPMENT_FIREBASE) {
  
  const DEV_PLUGINS = [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),             // ENABLE HMR
    new webpack.HashedModuleIdsPlugin()                   // INCLUDE HASH IN MODULE IDS AND FILENAMES
  ];
  const PLUGINS = config.plugins.concat(DEV_PLUGINS);     // MERGE COMMON AND DEV PLUGINS

  config = {
    ...config,
    watch: true,
    mode: "development",
    devtool: "inline-source-map",
    plugins: PLUGINS,
    output: {
      filename: "[name].[hash:5].js",
      path: path.resolve(__dirname, "public"),           // OUTPUT FILES WILL BE IN /public
      publicPath: "/"
    },
    resolve: {
      ...config.resolve,
      alias: {
        ...config.resolve.alias,
        ["react-dom"]: "@hot-loader/react-dom"
      }
    }
  };
}
```

**firebase.json**

```
{
  "firestore": {
    "rules": "firestore.rules",
    "indexes": "firestore.indexes.json"
  },
  "functions": {
    "predeploy": "npm --prefix \"$RESOURCE_DIR\" run build"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",                     // <---- SERVING FILES FROM /public
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ],
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/app.html"
      }
    ]
  },
  "storage": {
    "rules": "storage.rules"
  },
  "emulators": {
    "functions": {
      "port": 5001
    },
    "firestore": {
      "port": 8080
    },
    "hosting": {
      "port": 5000
    },
    "ui": {
      "enabled": true
    }
  }
}
```

So I've opened two terminals and I did the following:

**TERMINAL 1**

```
npm run start-firebase-build

// THIS WILL RUN THE BUILD FOR FIREBASE IN /public IN WATCH MODE (SO IT CAN BE HOT RELOADED)
```

**TERMINAL 2**

```
firebase emulators:start

// START ALL FIREBASE EMULATORS
```

---

**THE RESULT:**

Everything works. But I get no HMR. From what I can see from the script logs, Webpack is doing its thing (regarding reloading the modules), but I have to refresh the page in order to get Firebase to get the new bundle version.

**QUESTION**

Is it possible to develop using firebase hosting emulator and still get hot reloading while making changes to the front-end code?

I mean, if this is not possible, a solution to this could be just use `firestore` and `functions` emulators while still using `webpack-dev-server` as the "hosting provider", but I kind of "lose communication" with the hosting settings from `firebase.json`.

Imagine I have a `buildSitemap` cloud function that responds to the URL `/sitemap.xml`. That information is stored in `firebase.json` and that rewrite is done by Firebase hosting.

**firebase.json**

```
"rewrites": [
  {
    "source": "/sitemap.xml",
    "function": "buildSitemap"
  },
]
```

How do people usually handle this?

Comment: I'm not sure I get the idea, Firebase is a DB, Webpack HMR ment to reload app files when they change... what is your idea?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Firebase is more than a DB. It's a "backend as a service" product that incorporates hosting, data storage, cloud functions and also a realtime database/firestore that you can use. When you are developing, there a package called `firebase-tools` that allows you to serve your local content to your dev environment. I was just thinking if it's possible to enable some kind of hot reload into this feature.

Comment: Hot reload of what? :]

Comment: @felixmosh I mean hot reload of the changes I'm doing to the code in development. Webpack in `--watch` mode will auto re-build everything and injected the updated modules into the build files. I was thinking if firebase could auto update that. But I think now that this is not possible.

Comment: It can be done, but you need to decide what firebase should update... For example I've created i18next-hmr package which attaches to the build an hmr capabilities for translation files.